# How can I set an image in libgdx with a textureregion

Tags: android, image, libgdx, drawable, texture-atlas

I have just started to use `TexturePacker`, `TextureAtlas` and `TextureRegions` in my app.

I currently have a class called card, that extends `Image`, and I want to be able to set the graphic on a card as something from my atlas.

I can do this fine when I create the card as one of the many constructors for `Image` is `Image(TextureRegion textureRegion)`.

However, my card will need to change graphic during my game, and I need to be able to set this also from the atlas.

I can currently only find a way of changing the `Image` by setting the `Drawable` on it.

Is this the only way, seeing as there is a constructor to set the graphic using a `TextureRegion`, I find it odd that I can't do the same with a setter method?

If not, how should I go about this? Can I convert a `TextureRegion` into a `Drawable`? Should I cache this somewhere to save processing the `TextureRegion` into a `Drawable` each time? I am using an `AssetManager` to give me the `TextureAtlas`, so I presume there is only one instance of the `TextureAtlas`, but that won't hold true if I keep having to convert the `TextureRegion` into a `Drawable` will it? I'll have to cache this myself won't I?

Comment: Could you use something like:    
`image.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(TextureRegion)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simple way to convert TextureRegion to Drawable (which is btw interface) by creating [TextureRegionDrawable](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/TextureRegionDrawable.html) object:

```
    TextureRegion region = ...

    drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(region);
```

More reasonable for me seems to be just creating two Images and switch between them using

```
    image.setVisible(isVisible);
```

If you need to change textures one to another all the time you hould consider using [Animation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html) object to achieve this

Comment: While I was sleeping I was thinking about having two images inside the card class instead of one and changing it. I agree that I think this might be the way to go, which will then not need your helpful code, but at least it's an answer if I need it in the future or it others need it.

Comment: I am having trouble with this two image thing. Before my card extended Image, but if I now want to contain two Images within the one class, I decided to extend Actor instead. But I now have no idea on how to actually draw the Image inside the Actor. I think I might have to Override the draw method but I'm having no luck with that.

Comment: use [Group](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html) instead :)

Comment: I may look into that, but I've actually got it working with your first bit of code and it's waaaay quicker and smoother than it was before. So I might just leave it like that, but will keep the Group in mind in case anything ever gets a hit in performance in the future. Cheers